# Alignment, modulo; "Consequently it can rely on ESP = 12 modulo 16 at every function entry."

Tags: assembly, alignment, modularity, modular, modulo

I wonder if anyone can explain the use of "modulo" here:

> The Gnu compiler version 3.x and later for 32-bit Linux and Mac OS X makes the stack
>   pointer aligned by 16 at every function call instruction. Consequently it can rely on ESP = 12
>   modulo 16 at every function entry. *

BTW I know that the word size here is four bytes, and that 12 modulo 16 is 12. Other than that I really don't understand the statement that ESP = 12 modulo 16.

- From http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf

Comment: It's "modulo 16" aligned **before** the function call, the `call` instruction itself will put 4 bytes into stack (the return address in 32 bit mode), breaking the 0-alignment to -4 (-4 positive_modulo 16 = 12) ; at function entry (after `call` was executed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is the standard mathematical meaning, `x mod y` is the rest of `x div y`, where `div` is the integer division.
Modulus naturally arises when there is a periodicity over the natural numbers, to see this, just take compute `x mod 5` for the first 30 numbers.

Alignment is a requirement that an address is multiple of some number *n*, since *x* is multiple of *n* iif *x mod n == 0*, this links the modulus with the alignment.

The modulus over the naturals is one operation where it is easy to visualize the [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group): when aligning an address at the *n*-boundary, there are *n* possible cases to considers, despite a possibly infinite set of addresses.
For example, to align and address at the 4-boundary, addresses like 1, 5, 9, 13, ... are all equivalent since they are one value above a multiple of 4.
For all of them, we just need to add 3.

So, for an alignment at the *n*-boundary we only consider the cases where the address is 0, 1, 2, ... *n*-1 bytes above a multiple of *n*.

The wording "ESP = 12 modulo 16" means that `esp` is 12 bytes above an address multiple of 16.
Note that being 12 bytes above a multiple of 16 is equal to being 4 bytes below the next multiple of 16.
Visualizing `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15` we can go to the right by adding 1 and to the left by subtracting 1.

The reason `esp` is 12 modulo 16 after a call is that if, when an instruction like `call function` is executed, the stack is aligned on 16 bytes (i.e. `esp` is 0 modulo 16) then immediately after the call the stack is 4 bytes lower<sup>1</sup> (due to the `call` instruction pushing the return address) and thus 12 bytes from the previous multiple of 16.

```
... 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
                              ^           ^-- Before the call                    
                              |__ After the call
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Remember, the stack grows *down*.